# How to get DISTINCTCOUNT in GROUPBY table

Tags: dax

I have a table 'Report' which contain records of inspection from [StartDate] to [EndDate].
Inspections don't appear every day, so I have [ReportDate] too, but in one day I can have a few inspections.
My table 'Report' has column: A, B, C, StartDate, EndDate, ReportDate.
I want to receive grouping table which will contain number of days when inspection took place.
This number of days should summary DISTINCTCOUNT of [ReportDate].
My problem is that I can not use DISTINCTCOUNT inside of GROUPBY().
So how I can calculate DISTINCTCOUNT?
How to change below DAX statement?

```
New Table = 
    GROUPBY('Report'
            ,'Report'[A]
            ,'Report'[B]
            ,"Start Time", MIN ( CURRENTGROUP(), 'Report'[StartDate] )
            ,"End Time", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP(), 'Report'[EndDate] )
            ,"Days", COUNTAX ( CURRENTGROUP(), 'Report'[ReportDate] )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `SUMMARIZE`:

```
New Table =
SUMMARIZE(
    'Report',
    'Report'[A],
    'Report'[B],
    "Start Time", MIN( 'Report'[StartDate] ),
    "End Time", MAX( 'Report'[EndDate] ),
    "Days", COUNTA( 'Report'[ReportDate] ),
    "Distinct Days", DISTINCTCOUNT( Report[ReportDate] )
)
```

Comment: It is not a solution. Min, Max or other function will work in full table context so you will receive the same value in every record.
I have checked its.

Comment: @PrzemekP I have no idea what you mean. The max and min for each returned row will be evaluated within the row context, so they will not at all be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You directed me to a different solution.
I used twice GROUPBY statement and receive a proper value.

```
New Table = 
  GROUPBY(
    GROUPBY('Report'
            ,'Report'[A]
            ,'Report'[B]
            ,'Report'[ReportDate] 
            ,"Start Time", MIN ( CURRENTGROUP(), 'Report'[StartDate] )
            ,"End Time", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP(), 'Report'[EndDate] )
            )
      ,'Report'[A]
      ,'Report'[B]
      ,"Start Time", MIN ( CURRENTGROUP(), [StartDate] )
      ,"End Time", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP(), [EndDate] )
      ,"Days", COUNTAX ( CURRENTGROUP(), [ReportDate] )
      )
```